# Coding a horizontal drop down leaves links on top of eachother

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to code a drop down menu where the hovered over list item displays a list of links horizontally.

What is happening with my code right now is that all the links are right on top of each other, and I can't for the life of me figure out how to fix them.

I've tried adding height and width, and then adjusting the padding, margins, you name it. Somehow using display: inline; hasn't been enough to accomplish this.

If anyone could help me out with this, that would be much appreciated.

```
<header>
    <nav>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <h1><img alt="logo" src="logosmall.jpg" />
                    <a href="home.html"><strong>New Ideas</strong>Education</a>
                </h1>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html" class="current">about us</a></li>
                    <li>teachers
                        <ul>
                            <li>Literature</li>
                            <li>International</li>
                            <li>Staff</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="index-2.html">lessons</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index-3.html">reviews</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

And the CSS:

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
}

header nav {
}

header nav ul {
    background: #fff;
    padding: 2px 0 0 0;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    display: inline;
}

header nav ul:after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}

header nav ul ul:after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: inline;
    margin: 0 20px 0 0;
}

header nav ul li {
    float: left;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #757575;
    display: inline;
}

header nav ul li:hover > ul {
    color: #06cbe2;
    display: inline-table;
    padding: 5px 60px;
    margin: 0 20px 0 0;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
}

header nav ul li:hover a {
    color: #06cbe2;
}

header nav ul li a {
    display: inline;
    color: #757575;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

header nav ul ul {
    background: #fff;
    padding: 0px 20px 0px 0px;
    list-style: none;
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    display: none;
}

header nav ul ul li {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline;
    margin: 0 30px 0 0;
    color: #757575;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 10px -60px;
    font-size: 10pt;
}

header nav ul ul li a {
    padding: 10px -60px;
    color: #757575;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: inline-table;
    font-size: 6pt;
}

header nav ul ul li a:hover a {
    color: #06cbe2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

firstly make sure where and how you wanted to display the controls, if you saying all controls are sitting on over the other then all those positions have same value, the css have same values for almost all ID and Class, I can give you and example to fix and it might help you to fix your problem

Imagine you need two dropdown list one is on left and one is on right side then do this
NOTE(its just an example)

```
<div id=Main>
<div id=left></div>
<div id=right></div>
</div>
```

now provide height and width as 100% to "**Main**", then provide css for  "left" as below

```
   #left
{
height:100%;
width:50%;
border:1px solid black;
background-color: #ffffff;
float:left;
}

 #right
{
height:100%;
margin-left:50%;
border:1px solid black;
background-color: #ffffff;
float:right;
}
```

and inside to those div's use your dropdown controls or any controls and modify the width if you want, Let me know if it works, will help you